# Is there any way to find out , when the user had updated his profile last time

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, sharepoint-rest-api, user-profile-service

I want to know the date and time , when user had last updated his profile

Answer (score 2):

In SharePoint On-Premises, we can get recent user profile changes using the Change Log.

```
UserProfileChangeCollection changes=profileManager.GetUserProfile("domainname\\username").GetChanges(changeQuery);
```

Refer to: [How to: Get Recent User Profile Changes Using the Change Log](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms517376(v%3Doffice.14))

Unfortunately, there is not an API to achieve it for SharePoint Online currently.

Official document: [UserProfile members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.userprofiles.userprofile_members.aspx)